# Sorting Strings from file in C

Tags: c, string, file, sorting

I've recently taken up learning C. And now I want to try my hand at sorting some strings from a file. When I try to run it, I get "segmentation fault".
Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int compare (const void * a, const void * b ) {
  return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}

int main() {
static const char filename[] = "t1.txt";

char line1[1023];
char line2[1023];

FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
char filetext[1023][1023];
int i=0;
if ( file != NULL )
{
    while ( fgets ( filetext[i], sizeof filetext, file ) != NULL )
    {
        fputs ( filetext[i], stdout );
  i++;
    }
    fclose ( file );
}
else
{
    perror ( filename );
}

int n;

printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");

for( n = 0 ; n < i; n++ ) {
    printf("%s", filetext[n]);
}

qsort(filetext, i, sizeof(filetext[0]), (int (*)(const void*,const void*))strcmp);

printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");

for( n = 0 ; n < i; n++ ) {
    printf("%s", filetext[n]);
}   

return 0;
}
```

For example I want to turn:
File: t1
Priority9 cat
Priority2 ls
Priority7 cat mysort.h

into

Priority2 ls
Priority7 cat mysort.h
Priority9 cat

by calling "cat t1 j mysort" or "mysort < t1"

Comment: `qsort(filetext, i, sizeof(char), compare);` --> `qsort(filetext, i, sizeof(filetext[0]), (int (*)(void*,void*)strcmp);` and `#include <stdlib.h>`, `while ( fgets ( filetext[i], sizeof filetext, file ) != NULL )
` : `sizeof(filetext[0])`

Comment: i have type :`(int (*)(void*,void*)` --> `(int (*)(const void*, const void*))`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Changed it to this: qsort(filetext, i, sizeof(filetext[0]), (int ( * )(const void * ,const void*))strcmp); and included <stdlib.h>. Now the error is gone but it doesn't sort it. I added "const" to "void" because I get a long error without it.

Comment: do you apply Blue Ice's ansewer?

Comment: `int i=1;` -> `int i=0;` and `for( n = 1 ; n <= i; n++ ) {` --> `for( n = 0 ; n < i; n++) {`

Comment: Yes I did. It doesn't sort, however.

Comment: but it work fine to me. do you change this?: `while ( fgets ( filetext[i], sizeof filetext, file ) != NULL )`

Comment: Edited my, code in the question. Did I miss anything?

Comment: you forgot change `fgets` part. `sizeof filetext` to `sizeof(filetext[0])` or `sizeof(*filetext)` or `sizeof *filetext`

Comment: Where exactly? Not quite sure what to do with this: sizeof(filetext[0])

Comment: `while ( fgets ( filetext[i], sizeof filetext, file ) != NULL )` to `while ( fgets ( filetext[i], sizeof *filetext, file ) != NULL )`

Comment: Please remove all casts where you don't know **exactly** what you are doing and can explain why the cast is **neccessary** for correct working. Never muzzle the compiler, instead ask it to speak up: Use `-Wall -Wextra`, and handle all warnings appropriately.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks a whole lot! It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your `compare` function is producing `segmentation fault` is you are treating an address like it is a `char**` when it really needs to be treated like a `char*`. This is a result of how you have store the input data.

Let's take a smaller `filetext` to explore that a bit.

```
char filetext[4][10];
```

When you declare an array like that, the following statements are true:

```
filetext[0] == &filetext[0] == &filetext[0][0]
filetext[1] == &filetext[1] == &filetext[1][0]
filetext[2] == &filetext[2] == &filetext[2][0]
filetext[3] == &filetext[3] == &filetext[3][0]
```

For the purpose of `strcmp`, you have to treat `&filetext[0]` as a `char*`, not a `char**`.

Had you defined `filetext` a bit differently,

```
char* filetext[4];
filetext[0] = malloc(11);
filetext[1] = malloc(11);
filetext[2] = malloc(11);
filetext[3] = malloc(11);
```

Then,

```
filetext[0] != &filetext[0]
filetext[1] != &filetext[1]
filetext[2] != &filetext[3]
filetext[3] != &filetext[3]
```

If you pass this `filetext` to `compare`, you'll have to treat `&filetext[0]` as a `char**`, not a `char*`.

Hope that clears up things a bit for you.